# GMapModule missing from Primeng documentation

Tags: angular, google-maps, primeng

I noticed that the GMapModule doesn't appear in the Primeng documentation, even though I'm able to use it successfully in my Angular app. I'm wondering if this module has been deprecated or if there's a reason it's not included in the documentation.

If GMapModule is still supported, can someone point me in the direction of any resources or documentation that can help me understand how to work with it?

Here's the import statement I'm using to use the GMapModule in my app:

```
import { GMapModule } from 'primeng/gmap';
```

I'm using Angular version 15.2.4 and Primeng version 15.2.0,

Additionally, I found an example of using the GMap component in Primeng on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-primeng-gmap-component/), but I'm still unsure why this component isn't documented in the official Primeng documentation.

As a result, I'm not confident in my understanding of how to work with the GMapModule and would appreciate any help or guidance others can provide.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Best,
Reisy

Answer (score 1):

I dont see this included in the next beta 16.* version as well. Ideally it is a wrapper of original google maps and is not that flexible. Prefer to use native google maps libraries that would help to achieve your work specific needs. I tried primeng gmap p-gmap then focused to other libraries.
You could find more refernces at official google maps - [gmaps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation).
I find [googlemaps/js-api-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) more user friendly to add markers, draw polylines, reflect multi flight paths

If you follow the steps from googlemaps/js-api-loader make sure your refer

In cshtml:

```
div class="full" id="map">

</div>
```

In component.ts
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
 map: google.maps.Map;
```

//Load the google maps with api key registered from google maps developer api registration

```
 var loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: '**your key from google maps[please note this is billable based on user requests]',
      version: "weekly",
      libraries: ["places"]
    });

    loader
      .load()
      .then((google) => {
        //this.initMap();
      });
  }

const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: { lat: 17.3850, lng: 78.4867}
      });
```